# Repeat audio play without overlap

Tags: audio

I would like to play "no mask mp3" whenever "no mask" is recognized, but I keep hearing the audio overlapping. How can I play with delay so that the audio does not overlap?
please help me thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0y26.png)

Comment: Please post a text code, not picture of code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.